# Openshift ImportError: No module named 'gridfs'

Tags: python, deployment, openshift, pymongo

I'm trying to deploy a Python application on Openshift, but I keep getting this following error

> ImportError: No module named 'gridfs'

This is the setup.py file

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='YourAppName',
      version='1.0',
      description='OpenShift App',
      author='Your Name',
      author_email='example@example.com',
      url='https://www.python.org/community/sigs/current/distutils-sig',
      install_requires=['Flask>=0.7.2', 'MarkupSafe','pymongo','Pillow', 'python-pymongo'],
     )
```

Comment: Do a pip freeze to see what versions are installed of all your packages and report back. Maybe you have a version incompatibility.

Comment: Gridfs is package which is implementation of Gridfs on top of Pymongo. Try install Gridfs using `easy_install` or `pip`

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting,

> ImportError: No module named 'gridfs'

then run,

```
python -m pip install pymongo
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install pymongo
```